# The direct sum of two subspaces of $m \times n$ matrices is the subspace of all $m \times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

Define the sets $$W_1=\{A \in M_{m\times n}(F):A_{ij}=0,   i>j\}\\W_2=\{A \in M_{m\times n}(F):A_{ij}=0,   i\leq j\}.$$ Show that any matrix $C\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ can be uniquely decomposed as $C=C^{(1)}+C^{(2)}$ such that $C^{(1)}\in W_1$ and $C^{(2)}\in W_2$. Here, $M_{m\times n}(F)$ denotes the set of all matrices.

**Attempt:**

We show this by proving the following:

1. $M_{m\times n}(F)=W_1 \oplus W_2$
2. $W_1 \cap W_2=\{0\}$

Let $C \in M_{m\times n}(F)$. We have $C=C^{(1)}+C^{(2)}$ where
$$C^{(1)}_{i,j}=\begin{cases}  C_{i,j}   &\text{ if } \text{ i $\leq$ j}\\
          0  &\text{ if }  \text{ i>j}\end{cases}\\
C^{(2)}_{i,j}=\begin{cases}  0   &\text{ if } \text{ i $\leq$ j}\\
          C_{i,j}  &\text{ if }  \text{ i>j}\end{cases}$$

Therefore, $C \in W_1 + W_2$, and thus $M_{m \times n}(F)= W_1\oplus W_2$.

At this point, I am wondering whether the set equality has been completely proven. Have I shown only one direction of the subset inclusion, or is this enough to show the set equality?

For the next part of the proof, let $C \in W_1 \cap W_2$. 
$$C\in W_1 \implies C_{i,j}= 0 \text{ if }   i>j\\
C\in W_2 \implies C_{i,j}= 0 \text{ if }  i\leq j.$$ Thus, $C=0$, and hence, $W_1 \cap W_2 =\{0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your proof does not imply that $M_{m\times n}(F)=W_1 \oplus W_2$, but show that $M_{m\times n}(F)\subseteq W_1 \oplus W_2$.

To show the reverse direction, note that if $C\in W_1 \oplus W_2$, then $C\in M_{m\times n}(F)$. Thus, $W_1 \oplus W_2\subseteq M_{m\times n}(F)$. Hence, $$M_{m\times n}(F)\subseteq W_1 \oplus W_2\subseteq M_{m\times n}(F)\implies M_{m\times n}(F)=W_1 \oplus W_2.$$